# Decode Ascii string values from reverse-engineered lua file

Tags: python, java

I decompiled a lua file with unluac and it turns out all the string variables are not readable and are instead ascii encoded

```
clues = {
  {
    answer = {
      "\216\173",
      "\216\177",
      "\216\168",
      "\216\167",
      "\216\161"
    },
    text = "\216\173\217\138\217\136\216\167\217\134\032\216\178\216\167\216\173\217\129\032\217\138\216\186\217\138\216\177\032\217\132\217\136\217\134\032\216\172\217\132\216\175\217\135",
    syllables = {
      {"\216\173", "\216\177"},
      {"\216\168", "\216\167"},
      {"\216\161"}
    }
```

How do i go about decoding the whole file `ignoring any non ascii characters` in python or java?

Comment: Please note that this may not be ACII encoding due to the value ranges (ascii ranges from 0 to 127). It may be UTF-8 (although the resulting text does not make sense to me) or a custom enconding scheme. Got any code using these strings?

Comment: The strings are  in Arabic. I was able to decode each individual string value using this tool `www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/ascii/` 
The string at line 10 =" `حيوان زاحف يغير لون جلده` ". the file i decompiled is 15k lines, and impossible to do that manually, so i wondered how i could achieve that

Answer (score 1):

> How do i go about decoding the whole file ignoring any non ascii
>   characters in python or java?

did you consider replacing the symbols? You can use a regex as simple as that one:

```
\\\d{3}
```

To find all values to replace. For example, this does the trick in python:

```
text = r"""clues = {
  {
    answer = {
      "\216\173",
      "\216\177",
      "\216\168",
      "\216\167",
      "\216\161"
    },
    text = "\216\173\217\138\217\136\216\167\217\134\032\216\178\216\167\216\173\217\129\032\217\138\216\186\217\138\216\177\032\217\132\217\136\217\134\032\216\172\217\132\216\175\217\135",
    syllables = {
      {"\216\173", "\216\177"},
      {"\216\168", "\216\167"},
      {"\216\161"}
  }"""
import re

def decode(match):
    code = int(match.group(1))
    return chr(code)

print re.sub(r'\\(\d{3})', decode, text)
```

Also, please note that this is [Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) and not ASCII per se.

Comment: Just tried it. It didn't output arabic text. Guess the encoding is not right? Output --> `ﾎ{ﾏ8ﾏ^ﾎwﾏ\ﾎ8ﾎwﾎ{ﾏ 9ﾏ8ﾎ86ﾏ8ﾎﾏZﾏ^ﾏ\ﾎzﾏZﾎ}ﾏ]` expected output --> `حيوان زاحف يغير لون جلده`

Comment: It works (text = "حيوان زاحف يغير لون جلده"). Please be sure to treat the text you are reading as a raw string so python doesn't try to interpret the backslashes as escape sequences. Adapted my answer